# jQuery inserting html as text instead of DOM object

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to insert a DOM element using jQuery but it keeps being inserted as text instead.

```
var newImg = "<h1>Hi</h1>";
    $("li").each(function myFn(){
        this.addEventListener("mouseover", function myFn2 () {
                             this.before(newImg);
                              })
    });
```

Comment: Side note, the each is unnecessary.  `$('li').on('mouseover', function () { ... });` would perform the same function

Comment: ah ok, ill tidy that up too, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `console.log(this)` you should find that it is not a jQuery object inside the event handler.  You will want to wrap it with $() before you use the before method to use the jQuery method.

```
$(this).before(newImg);
```

```js
var newImg = "<h1>Hi</h1>";
$("li").each(function myFn() {
  this.addEventListener("mouseover", function myFn2() {
    $(this).before(newImg);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Wee</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That does make it an object, but it displays on the page as [object Object] now

Comment: The code snippet in the answer doesn't insert [object Object] so something you are doing is different.